# IdentityServer4 with client MVC and WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

i'm trying to authenticate  mvc and webapi client using identityserver on same application asp.net core basically i have seperate host for identityserver and another project for the client which have mvc controller and apicontroller on same app. is that possible to handle two different type of application authorization ?

Comment: This should be fine, presumably you want the MVC controllers to require authentication via IDS and then be able to access the API via an access token as well as direct access to the API from other clients? Those other clients would first need to authenticate with your IDS and get themselves an access token. Are you hitting a specific issue when you try this?

Comment: @Matt thanks for the reply actually i'm new to identityserver and trying to understand it's functionalities could you please give me some code example how to do it?

Comment: You could check out the identity server 4 documentation. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/
I think what you want to achieve should be doable. I've done similar setup last year, but don't remember much of details.

Comment: Yeah follow the samples in the docs linked in the previous comment, they build on each other and will get you up and running.